# How to track a Java app's usage without rewriting its source code?

Tags: java, user-interface, analytics, tracking

I would like to track clicks to `JButton`s, log page views, see time spent on a specific page, etc...

Ideally, I would just like to add a one liner in the constructor or something along the lines of `Analytics.startTracking()`

Is there such a framework that already does this?

If not, how would you go about implementing one?

Comment: Why don´t you write it by your own? doesn´t seem to hard to implement on the graphical components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any framework that does this. You can use `Toolkit.addAWTEventListener` to capture all AWT events and use that information.